# Stored procedure to update column based on Min Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, aggregate

I have been able to find similar issues to one I am having, but not that helps me to resolve!

I have a table that contains job data (`tablea`), schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tablea](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [JobDesc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [RequiredDate] [datetime] NULL
```

Certain jobs within this table provide components for other jobs in the same table, going forward I will call the jobs that provide components "Production Jobs" and the job receiving the components "sub jobs" - there is nothing within the table that links the rows.

There is another table (`tableb`)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableb](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_JobProducts_JobNo]  DEFAULT (''),
    [SubJobNo] [varchar](32) NULL
```

This contains the "production job" job number (`tableb.JobNo`), and in the same row, the job number of the "sub job" (`tableb.SubJobNo`)

nb if a "production job" provides components for 7 x "sub jobs" there will be 7 x rows in tableb

I have an objective to execute a stored procedure that will update the required date column of the "production job" row of tablea with the **EARLIEST** date of the required date column of the associated "sub job". When executing the stored procedure, a unique identifier will be used as the variable - this will be the title of the "production job".

My attempt is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDate] 
    @Title varchar(32),
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE ta1
    SET ta1.RequiredDate = ta2.RequiredDate
    FROM tablea ta1
    INNER JOIN tableb tb ON ta1.JobNo = tb.JobNo
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT JobNo, MIN(RequiredTime) 
         GROUP BY JobNo 
         FROM tablea) ta2 ON tb.SubJobNo = ta2.JobNo
    WHERE ta1.JobDesc = @Title
```

This has got me stumped so any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is going wrong with your attempt? Are you getting a specific error message? Is it updating the wrong data? Please be specific.

Comment: Hi Robert. It updates the date, but it seems to do it with the 1st "sub job" date - not the earliest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to say that tabalea relates to tableb then back to tablea to get to required time then just change the cte to something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDate] 
    @Title varchar(32),
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH cte AS (
       SELECT
          ta.JobNo
          ,MIN(ta2.RequiredTime) as NewRequiredDate
       FROM
          tablea ta
          INNER JOIN tableb tb
          ON ta.JobNo = tb.JobNo
          INNER JOIN tablea ta2
          ON tb.SubJobNo = ta2.JobNo
       WHERE
          ta.JobDesc = @Title
       GROUP BY
          ta.JobNo
    )

    UPDATE ta
    SET RequiredDate = c.NewRequiredDate
    FROM tablea ta
    INNER JOIN cte c
    ON ta.JobNo = c.JobNo
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help - yes I am trying to go from tablea > tableb > table a. Using your 2nd code I am getting the following error:

Comment: Column 'ta.JobNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: sorry I had left out the group by just trying to give you a direction.  I put it in, but the idea is to use a CTE to do your aggregation like you normally would in a select and then join to update your original table.

Comment: You are a beautiful man! Sorry for my ignorance and poor etiquette when asking the question! Your answer has worked a treat.

Comment: not at all glad to help, and learning how to ask is part of the process.  Welcome to SO!